# Unable to compile data from multiple dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stock

I have a selection of stocks with stock prices. I am trying to compile the data in to one data frame for comparison.

I am trying to achieve a dataframe which is closing stocks prices in shown in columns.

```
def compile_data():
    main_df = pd.DataFrame(read_create_giant_df(file_in), dtype='RIC')
    for count, in enumerate(RIC):
        df = (main_df.format(RIC))
        df.set_index('Date', inplace=True)
        df.rename(columns={'Close' : RIC}, inplace=True)
        df.drop(['Open', 'High', ' Low', 'Adj Close'], 1 , inplace=True)
        if main_df.empty:
            main_df = df
        else:
            main_df = main_df(df, how='outer')
        print(main_df.head())
compile_data()
```

I keep getting the error data type 'RIC' not understood, I have tried to define RIC as its a column in the data frames I want to combine.

By any chance is there an easier way?

Comment: It looks like the issue (though I see more ahead in your code) is coming from `dtype='RIC'` on line 2. 'RIC' is not a valid dtype, like int, str, np.float64, etc. If you want to specify the dtype for a specific column you can include e.g. `dtypes={'RIC'=str}` as a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Do not specify `, dtype='RIC'`, as it is not integer / float / other
valid data type recognized by numpy.

---

Rather than `main_df.format(RIC)`,
refer to the column as

```
main_df.RIC
```

or perhaps

```
main_df['RIC']
```